# Using msvcrt with Mingw-w64

Tags: c, windows, mingw-w64

I'm trying to use the Mingw-w64 toolchain provided by LH_Mouse, [version 10.2.1](https://gcc-mcf.lhmouse.com/mingw-w64-gcc-mcf_20200920_10.2.1_x64_f7584239ce2c0fc2fdb1ae66ffb2020c386cfc3b.7z).
When compiling this small program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int wmain()
{
    wprintf(L"Hello world!\n");
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

with the following command:

```
gcc.exe test.c -o test64.exe -municode -s -Os -Wall -nostdlib -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -e wmain
```

I get an error: undefined reference to `__mingw_vfwprintf'

*Z:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: R:\Temp\ccDSsj2M.o:test.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfwprintf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

I previously used Mingw-w64 7.3.0 provided on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) and everything worked fine.

Of course I can use the stdlib (and in this case there is no error) but this increases the size of the executable.

I have read that some changes have been done recently to support UCRT. Is it related?

Is there a way to use msvcrt like before?

**Edit:** using -lmingwex does not really help. If located after -lmsvcrt, it produces a huge amount of varied "undefined reference" errors. If located before, we got several "undefined reference" to ___chkstk_ms, and one to _pei386_runtime_relocator.
The first ones can be removed by adding -lgcc after -lmingwex. For the last "undefined reference", I have found nothing. Adding -lmingw32 does not help, no matter its location.

So for now, the only possibilities I see are to either modify stdio.h, or create my own declarations.
Well, I use mingw since many years and its not the biggest issue I encountered. But I am a bit disappointed that it affects such basic functions.

Comment: In the [upstream](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) version, I notice one of the [changes](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/versions) for v8.0.0 is "__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO now automatically enabled in C99 and C11 mode when not using UCRT by Pali Rohár". (I'm not sure if that also affects wide-character stdio.)

Comment: C99 compliance, -lmingwex to resolve it.

Comment: Why I don't have the right to say that -lmingwex produces a lot of errors?

Comment: wmain receives a `wchar_t*`: `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[]);`. If you want to use `TCHAR *` then use `_tmain` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019. Using `TCHAR` with `wmain` makes no sense

Comment: Yes, but in fact both are incorrect, because of the command used to compile: argc and argv are not initialized.
So here, the only correct way to write that is to remove them. I have edited to change that.

Comment: Why did you add `-nostdlib -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -e wmain`, this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @ssbssa: for this small example: with -nostdlib, the exe takes 3.5KB. Without: 40KB.

Comment: I haven't tried it (I still have mingw-w64-v7.0.0), but from reading the source adding `-D_CRTBLD` might work.

Comment: @ssbssa: Didn't try that.... Thanks a lot! This is the answer. Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as solved.
Don't know what "BLD" means though.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile your application with `-nostdlib` option which means that standard C functions (like `printf`, `scanf`, `wprintf`, ...) are not available for your application. Therefore you should not include standard C header files (like `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, ...) and also you should not use `wprintf` in your application.

If you really want to standard C function with `-nostdlib` option then you have to write your own C header files and also your own implementation of standard C functions (like `wprintf`).

What you did was to include MinGW's `stdio.h` header file which calls lot of standard C functions and also internal MinGW functions and then told gcc (via `-nostdlib` to not link these standard functions and neither internal MinGW functions. Which obviously resulted in lot of linker errors.

Then you have tried to manually link `msvcrt.dll` library but it failed too as this Windows library does not contain internal MinGW functions used in MinGW's `stdio.h` header file.

If you really want not use standard C functions from gcc/MinGW (via `-nostdlib` option) but rather directly via Windows `msvcrt.dll` library then you have to use also Windows `stdio.h` header file and not MinGW one. But beware that Windows header file `stdio.h` is not supported for gcc compiler and it also does not have to work.

So you should first answer questions, why you are trying to use standard C functions (like `wprintf`) without standard C library with gcc compiler? This sounds really strange and such thing is common only in freestanding environment or for bare-metal applications (like firmware, bootloader, kernel, ...). Are you workarounding some other bug which you have not mentioned?

And to answer your question, why in previous version it (probably) worked fine. Older version of gcc compiled C code according to C89 standard (with GCC extensions). New version of gcc started to compile C code according to C11 standard. Windows library `msvcrt.dll` provides only subset of standard C functions and only for C89 standard. For this reason MinGW provides its own implementation (or fixes) for some standard C functions to be compliant with C99 and C11 standards. As older gcc compiled your application as C89 code and manually linked `msvcrt.dll` library provided somehow compatible implementation for `printf` and `wprintf`, it resulted in final exe file without errors. Now with new gcc you are compiling your application as C11 code and you are trying to call C11 `wprintf` function but this function in `msvcrt.dll` is not compatible with C11 and therefore you get lot of errors.

Windows provides C11 standard functions in UCRT libraries. `msvcrt.dll` provides only subset of C89.

So you really should not compile your application with `-nostdlib` if your intention is to produce executable application and use standard C functions.

You can instruct new gcc to compile your C application as C89 with option `-std=c89`. This should instruct new gcc to behave like old gcc.